# TCP Idle connections growing on Azure Web App

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, azure, tcp

I have a mobile application which connects to Azure web services written in Spring Hibernate which communicates to Azure SQL server for performing data operations.
In hibernate we dont have any connection manager configured. We are using Hibernate sessionFactory for managing the connections.
Recently after too many users using the app, we found that the Azure automatically restarting the services after reaching the max connection limits of Azure which is 1920 TCP connections.
TCP connections once used either go into CLOSE_WAIT state or TIME_WAIT state.
They are not properly closing the connections.
Is this related to some Azure VM Server not closing the connections or has to do with the Java coding style used.

Pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.mastek</groupId>
<artifactId>transaction-rs</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>transaction-rs</name>

<properties>
    <springframework.version>4.0.6.RELEASE</springframework.version>
    <hibernate.version>4.3.6.Final</hibernate.version>
    <sqlserver.version>4.0</sqlserver.version>
    <swagger-version>1.3.0</swagger-version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- MS SQL server driver -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
        <version>${sqlserver.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- orika mapper -->
    <dependency>
     <groupId>ma.glasnost.orika</groupId>
     <artifactId>orika-core</artifactId>
     <version>1.4.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- resteasy api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.13.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jaxb-provider</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.13.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.13.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jackson-provider</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.13.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-spring</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.13.Final</version>
    </dependency>
     <!-- Resteasy Servlet Container Initializer -->
     <!-- scope 'provided' for JBoss AS -->
 <!-- <dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-servlet-initializer</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.11.Final</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>  -->

<!-- slf4j and logger -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- swagger for documentation -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- junit -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- commons -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mastek.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>

        <!-- JSON to XML -->
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20160212</version>
   </dependency>

   <!--  Gson: Java to Json conversion -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
         <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
         <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!--  swagger start -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.wordnik</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs_2.9.1</artifactId>
        <version>${swagger-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.wordnik</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-annotations_2.9.1</artifactId>
        <version>${swagger-version}</version>
    </dependency>
<!--  swagger end -->

</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>transaction-rs</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

</project>
```

Persistence-config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx  http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">

<context:property-placeholder ignore-resource-not-found="true" location="file:/sdt/configuration/services.properties, file:../../sdt/configuration/services.properties, classpath:application.properties" />

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${transaction.service.jdbc.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${transaction.service.jdbc.url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${transaction.service.jdbc.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${transaction.service.jdbc.password}"/>
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean" >
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <list>
            <value>com.mastek.commons.data.entity</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">${hibernate.format_sql}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>       
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager"  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"
    class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"/>

</beans>
```

This is the part of my DAOImpl.java:

```
package com.mastek.security.data.service;
import static com.mastek.commons.util.ApplicationConstants.DELIMITER;
import static com.mastek.commons.util.ApplicationConstants.END;
import static com.mastek.commons.util.ApplicationConstants.GET_WEEK;
import static com.mastek.commons.util.ApplicationConstants.REGISTER_USER;
import static com.mastek.commons.util.ApplicationConstants.START;
import static com.mastek.commons.util.ApplicationConstants.USER_ID;
import static com.mastek.commons.util.ApplicationConstants.VEFIFY_USER;
import static com.mastek.commons.util.ApplicationConstants.GET_USER_BY_EMAIL;

import java.util.Date;

import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.mastek.commons.data.dao.impl.AbstractDAO;
import com.mastek.commons.data.entity.VWLoginUser;
import com.mastek.commons.data.entity.VWUser;
import com.mastek.commons.data.entity.VWWeekEnding;
import com.mastek.commons.domain.UserDO;
import com.mastek.commons.domain.WeekDO;
import com.mastek.commons.exception.DataStoreException;
import com.mastek.commons.exception.SystemException;
import com.mastek.commons.util.CommonUtil;

import ma.glasnost.orika.MapperFacade;

/**
* The Class RegistrationDAOImpl.
*/
@Repository
public class RegistrationDAOImpl extends AbstractDAO implements RegistrationDAO
{
/** The Constant logger. */
private static final Logger logger =         LoggerFactory.getLogger(RegistrationDAOImpl.class);

/** The mapper facade. */
@Autowired
private MapperFacade mapperFacade;

/**
 * This method verifies logged in user.
 *
 * @param surname the surname
 * @param userId the user id
 * @return the user do
 * @throws DataStoreException the data store exception
 */
@Override
public UserDO verifyUser(String surname, long userId) throws DataStoreException
{
    logger.info(VEFIFY_USER + DELIMITER + USER_ID + userId + DELIMITER + START);

    UserDO userDO = null;
    Session session = openSession();
    try
    {
        Query query = session.getNamedQuery("VWLoginUser.getUser");
        query.setLong("userId", userId);
        query.setString("surname", surname);
        VWLoginUser user = (VWLoginUser) query.uniqueResult();

        userDO = mapperFacade.map(user, UserDO.class);

    }
    catch (org.hibernate.exception.DataException de)
    {
        logger.error(VEFIFY_USER + DELIMITER + USER_ID + userId + DELIMITER + SystemException.Type.DE.getErrorCode() + DELIMITER + SystemException.Type.DE.getMessage());
        logger.error(VEFIFY_USER, de);
        throw new DataStoreException(new SystemException(SystemException.Type.DE, de));
    }
    catch (org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException jdbcce)
    {
        logger.error(VEFIFY_USER + DELIMITER + USER_ID + userId + DELIMITER + SystemException.Type.JDBCCE.getErrorCode() + DELIMITER + SystemException.Type.JDBCCE.getMessage());
        logger.error(VEFIFY_USER, jdbcce);
        throw new DataStoreException(new SystemException(SystemException.Type.JDBCCE, jdbcce));
    }
    catch (org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException sqlge)
    {
        logger.error(VEFIFY_USER + DELIMITER + USER_ID + userId + DELIMITER + SystemException.Type.SQLGE.getErrorCode() + DELIMITER + SystemException.Type.SQLGE.getMessage());
        logger.error(VEFIFY_USER, sqlge);
        throw new DataStoreException(new SystemException(SystemException.Type.SQLGE, sqlge));
    }
    finally
    {
        session.clear();
        session.close();
    }
    logger.info(VEFIFY_USER + DELIMITER + USER_ID + userId + DELIMITER + END);

    return userDO;
}
}
```

This is my AbstractDAO.java:

```
package com.mastek.commons.data.dao.impl;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

/**
* The Class AbstractDAO.
*/
public abstract class AbstractDAO
{

/** The session factory. */
@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

/**
 * Gets the session.
 *
 * @return the session
 */
protected Session getSession()
{
    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
}

/**
 * Open session.
 *
 * @return the session
 */
protected Session openSession()
{
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    return session;
}

/**
 * Persist.
 *
 * @param entity the entity
 */
public void persist(Object entity)
{
    getSession().persist(entity);
}

/**
 * Delete.
 *
 * @param entity the entity
 */
public void delete(Object entity)
{
    getSession().delete(entity);
}

/**
 * Gets the session factory.
 *
 * @return the session factory
 */
public SessionFactory getSessionFactory()
{
    return sessionFactory;
}

/**
 * Sets the session factory.
 *
 * @param sessionFactory the session factory
 */
public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory)
{
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
}

}
```

Comment: We are not explicitly closing the connections from our code. Its maintained by hibernate

Comment: The max TCP connection limits `1920` of Azure seems to comes from [here](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#cross-vm-numerical-limits). Is it? If you are using Hibernate for Spring web app, is there a connection pool like `C3PO` configured for Hibernate session factory? If so, is there the configuration option about  max pool size like `hibernate.c3p0.max_size` for session factory? Please improve your description and make the issue clear, such as post the content of `hibernate.cfg.xml` file & your webapp tier here.

Comment: Many thanks for the reply,

Comment: We are not using any connection pooling like C3P0. Also, we dont use hibernate.cfg.xml We are using autowired with pom.xml and persistence-config.xml